# installing a program on w7, .NET version 2.0 required

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am  tryng to install a program on windows 7 but when i run tha installer i get a error message sayng: Please install .NET Framework Version 2.0 before installing the tool.
As i know the .NET 2.0 should be installed with w7 allready. So what might be the problem? Maybe there is a way passbye the checking in the installation.. or extract it or do something.

Just for more info i think its a installshield setup launcher. I tried to extract it but its not possible, getting the .net 2.0 missing error. So what i managed to do is to extract the msi from exe. And now when i run the -msi with /passive option from cmd the it indeed bypasses the .net check and everything gets installed. Now the problem is that im getting all kind of errors in the application so looks like its still not installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is the program you install doesn't detect .NET 2.0 correctly. As you correctly mentioned, .NET 2.0 is pre-installed on Windows 7. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx) for complete picture.

Answer (score 0):

While .NET is part of Windows 7, it's an optional component, though - you can turn it off.

Open the "Windows features" dialogue (by pressing start and typing/selecting "Turn Windows features on or off"), and make sure the "Microsoft .NET framework 3.5.1" is indeed installed.

If you're seeing errors in your app then maybe there's a problem with your .NET installation, or you have a client profile or partial install.  What's the application you're installing - is it a server application?